# Zooming into the mouse, factoring in a camera translation? (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, c, opengl

Here is my issue, I have a scale point, which is the unprojected mouse position. I also have a "camera which basically translates all objects by X and Y. What I want to do is achieve zooming into mouse position.

I'v tried this:

```
   1. Find the mouse's x and y coordinates 
   2. Translate by (x,y,0) to put the origin at those coordinates
   3. Scale by your desired vector (i,j,k)
   4. Translate by (-x,-y,0) to put the origin back at the top left
```

But this doesn't factor in a translation for the camera.

How can I properly do this. Thanks

```
glTranslatef(controls.MainGlFrame.GetCameraX(),
    controls.MainGlFrame.GetCameraY(),0);
glTranslatef(current.ScalePoint.x,current.ScalePoint.y,0);

glScalef(current.ScaleFactor,current.ScaleFactor,0);
glTranslatef(-current.ScalePoint.x,-current.ScalePoint.y,0);
```

Comment: I might be understanding/getting this wrong but, instead of scaling the desired vector by (i,j,k) as you put have you tried translating the z axis to zoom in?

Comment: Need more information and clarity.  Perhaps source code?  Does "2. Translate by... " refer to projectionview matrix transformations?  In what way does this not "factor in a translation for the camera"? I guess that this is a 2D orthographic view, yes?

Comment: @thyrgle: "translating the z axis to zoom in?". In perspective projection, zooming is achieved by changing camera's FOV. NOT by moving along Z.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using glTranslate to move all the objects, you should try [glOrtho](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/). It takes as parameters the wanted left coords, right coords, bottom coords, top coords, and min/max depth.

For example if you call glOrtho(-5, 5, -2, 2, ...); your screen will show all the points whose coords are inside a rectangle going from (-5,2) to (5,-2). The advantage is that you can easily adjust the zoom level.

If you don't multiply by any view/projection matrix (which I assume is the case), the default screen coords range from (-1,1) to (1,-1).

But in your project it can be very useful to control the camera. Call this before you draw any object instead of your glTranslate:

```
float left = cameraX - zoomLevel * 2;
float right = cameraX + zoomLevel * 2;
float top = cameraY + zoomLevel * 2;
float bottom = cameraY - zoomLevel * 2;
glOrtho(left, right, bottom, top, -1.f, 1.f);
```

Note that cameraX and cameraY now represent the center of the screen.

Now when you zoom on a point, you simply have to do something like this:

```
cameraX += (cameraX - screenX) * 0.5f;
cameraY += (cameraY - screenY) * 0.5f;
zoomLevel += 0.5f;
```

Comment: glOrtho creates an orthographic projection - not a perspective one. This is desirable in some situations (e.g. 2D tile games) and not desirable in other (e.g. FPS). Anyway - moving the camera instead of all objects is the right way to do it.